# What is this device mounted on the fuselage of Lufthansa planes?

Tags: airliner

I noted the device shown in the photo mounted on top of the fuselage near the tail. The photo shows a smaller airbus (I think) but it is also present on several A380ies, and a Boeing 747. In fact, most, but not all Lufthansa planes (observed at Frankfurt airport) seem to have this but I haven't noted it yet with other airlines.

[image: Lufthansa-plane-at-Frankfurt-airport]

Comment: A satellite antenna for passenger internet. See https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14849/how-does-wifi-work-on-an-aircraft/14850#14850 and https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46544/how-does-an-airbus-aircraft-connect-to-the-internet/46547#46547

Comment: Thanks, that solves it (although without your comment, I could not have found the duplicate question) - my sample of non-Lufthansa planes was obviously too small.