# Does in-flight Wi-Fi require regulatory approval?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, regulations, icao-sarps

Does any country have regulations that require a certificate or approval of the aircraft that use portable Wi-Fi in flight? Is there an FAA or EASA regulation or advisory, or an ICAO document or advisory?

Comment: fyi, Wi-Fi does not stand for "Wireless Fidelity" [see this question](https://superuser.com/q/1086226/379161)

Comment: I've edited your question to try to make it clearer, I hope I didn't change it too much. But what does "use portable Wi-Fi in flight" mean? Are you asking if the aircraft's passenger Wi-Fi system requires approval, or if the crew needs approval to use it, or something else?

Comment: Thank you very much for this correction sir.  “use portable wi-fi in flight”. I mean. Some of the aircraft in some airline provide wifi for used by passenger for communication or browsing. I am looking for faa, icao or any state regulation. How to certified or approve this aircraft that provide wifi for passenger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAA [touches upon it in this letter](https://www.faa.gov/news/press_releases/news_story.cfm?cid=TW189&newsId=15254)

> Current FAA regulations require an aircraft operator to determine that
>   radio frequency interference from PEDs is not a flight safety risk
>   before the operator authorizes them for use during certain phases of
>   flight. Even PEDs that do not intentionally transmit signals can emit
>   unintentional radio energy. This energy may affect aircraft safety
>   because the signals can occur at the same frequencies used by the
>   plane’s highly sensitive communications, navigation, flight control
>   and electronic equipment. An airline must show it can prevent
>   potential interference that could pose a safety hazard. The PED ARC
>   report helps the FAA to guide airlines through determining that they
>   can safely allow widespread use of PEDs.

The operator is responsible for determining that [the unit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46544/how-does-an-airbus-aircraft-connect-to-the-internet/46547#46547) does not create any interference they link off to this document [which is pretty verbose](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/ped/media/PED_ARC_FINAL_REPORT.pdf) and outlines a lot of the info you may be looking for on this front.

[This document](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_91.21-1D.pdf) elaborates a bit more on the regulations

> Aircraft with an FAA-approved system— such as an Onboard Mobile
>   Telecommunications System (OMTS), Wireless Fidelity (WiFi), airborne
>   access systems (AASs), or Network Control Units (NCUs)—are considered
>   PED-tolerant for PEDs used with the installed system. If an aircraft
>   model has demonstrated tolerance for both transmitting and
>   non-transmitting PEDs, the operator may allow PED use during all
>   phases of flight on this aircraft model.

Aircraft need to be shown to be PED tolerant for Wifi units. You can find an AC covering whats [involved in that here](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_20-164A.pdf).