# What is this fuselage-side aerial used for?

Tags: aircraft-systems, feature-identification

[image: The aerial on the port fuselage]
([instagram.com](https://www.instagram.com/p/BWEVdSmlGfB/))

I have seen this picture, and this feature on the port fuselage called my attention. Does anybody know the purpose of this?

Answer (score 9):

One of the [features](https://aadvantagegeek.boardingarea.com/2013/08/15/eight-best-features-of-the-new-american-airlines-a319/) on this American Airlines Airbus A319 is the Gogo Inflight Internet.

> The A319 will be the first aircraft type in American’s fleet to use Gogo’s ATG-4 Wi-Fi solution. ATG-4 uses more antennas and better data compression technology to provide more robust and reliable service (August 15, 2013).

There's another one on the other side. It's part of the air-to-ground (ATG) internet setup that utilizes Gogo's cellular towers in the US and Canada, as opposed to [satellite internet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14849/14897).

[image]
([Left](http://concourse.gogoair.com/gogo-introduces-atg-4-flight-connectivity-technology-business-aviation/); [Right](http://concourse.gogoair.com/gogo-atg-4-work/)) Click to view.

---

Related external links:

- [Inside a Gogo ATG4 installation](https://blog.wandr.me/2014/07/inside-a-gogo-atg4-installation/)
- [How Does In-Flight Wi-Fi Really Work?](https://thepointsguy.com/2015/11/how-in-flight-wi-fi-works/)

Thanks to @mins for their help on the answer.